# False (old?) information in Close-Privilege description

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, privileges

Today I've been awarded with the *"Cast close and reopen votes"* Privilege (3000 Reputation).

So I read through the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) of said privilege and saw the following bulletpoints, formally highlighted with a freehand circle:

[image: cast and close vote privilege description]

The false information is clear to most users that actively report questions as duplicates.

One does not just post a link to report the question. Instead that person flags the question with the flag-button below each post.

This opens a dialog in which the duplicate option can be selected. Again, highlighted for clarity with a freehand-circle:

[image: flagging a question dialog]

After the flagging, the system then itself posts a link to the duplicate question, with the text:

> Possible duplicate of: *A Question already asked before*

So my question is: **Is this description (the one from the Close Privileges page) just old?**

Comment: I don't know if the system will let you flag after reaching the daily Close Vote limit, but indeed the text is wrong about manually posting comments.

Comment: @psubsee2003 That's not what this is talking about.  The problem is that the text is saying that users with less than 3k should comment (and not flag) if they think a question is a duplicate.  It appears to have been written before you could flag a post for closure.

Comment: @Stijn that is probably another question. Might be interesting to find out, although not really useful

Comment: If I remember correct, yes that was the case the last time I ran out of votes ~ a year ago @Stijn

Comment: @Lino There are multiple Meta posts re: can you flag for closure after having close-vote privileges. The answer is: No, you *can't* flag for closure, you can only vote for closure. All of the dialogs will say vote, and if you try to raise a close-flag through other methods (e.g. SE API) it's automatically converted to a close-vote. Once you're out of close-votes per day (50), you still can not flag for closure.

Comment: I think the problem is that this text mixes the “_not enough reputation_” with the “_out of votes_” cases. It should instead be something like: “_If you don't have enough reputation, you can flag. If you are out of votes or flags, post a comment as a hint for other people to handle it._”.

Comment: This is definitely not even possible; once you have 3k reputation, selecting the 'should be closed' reason in the flagging modal will open up the vote-to-close modal. You *cannot* cast a closure flag after 3k reputation. I don't think it's ever been possible in the past, either.